# how to toggle sort in javascript?

Tags: javascript

There are lots of examples about sorting but i couldn't understand anyone. Can anyone help to toggle sort when the button is clicked.

```
<button onclick="sortName()">Sort</button>

var contacts= [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "xyz",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "phone": "0000958331"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "abc",
  "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
  "phone": "0110958332"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "efg",
  "email": "def@gmail.com",
  "phone": "0220958333"
}
]

function sortName(){
 contacts.sort(function (a, b) {
 const x = a.name.toLowerCase();
 const y = b.name.toLowerCase();
 return (x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0);
});

console.log(contacts);
}
```

Link:https://codepen.io/sarash/pen/PjpLdd?editors=1010

Comment: This code works but i dont know how to make it toggle so when the button is clicked 2nd time the name should appear in descending order and so on.

Comment: You might look at the `localeCompare` method to compare two strings, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: If i could have understand so easily just googling it then why should i have to post it here

Comment: There is nothing actually doing the sorting.  Your return statement is just comparing the values of x and y and returning a 1 or a -1, but you're not passing anything to sort.  Additionally, you would need to take action based on that comparison.  There are literally dozens of ways to do this, for instance https://khan4019.github.io/front-end-Interview-Questions/sort.html.

Comment: Actually i am not showing any errors in this code i just wanted an idea that how do i make that button toggle so that the name will appear ascending to descending and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it toggle you can put a variable outside the called function to store current order and toggle it on every click:

```
var order = false;
var contacts= [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "xyz",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "phone": "0000958331"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "abc",
  "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
  "phone": "0110958332"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "efg",
  "email": "def@gmail.com",
  "phone": "0220958333"
}
]

function sortName(){
  order = !order;
  contacts.sort(function (a, b) {
    const x = a.name.toLowerCase();
    const y = b.name.toLowerCase();
    return (order ? x > y : x < y);
  });
  console.log(contacts);
}
```

Comment: its just showing from ascending to descending but i want the name to be appeared from descending to ascending also when the button is clicked second time

Comment: I changed the code and added `order` as the switch state.

Comment: Thanks Alinex, this is what i was looking for. You were the only one whose understood my problem.